# CakePHP Find function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

i am using the following statement.

```
$users = $this->User->find('all');
```

But in the database there are only 174 rows. but the query is returning 200 rows.

When i out put the content i see that a lot of rows are repeated.

Any idea why this behavior in cakephp ?

[image]

**Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `display_photo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscription_plan_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=177 ;
```

by trying to debug using this statment

```
echo $users = $this->User->find('count');
```

i get 200 itself.

Models: http://pastebin.com/p4bFPiUz

Comment: show your model structure of User, Dont you have any relationship with other table ?

Comment: how many rows does the table *actually* have? the count in phpmyadmin is approximate, as indicated by the footnote. do a `find->('all')` and output the results with a count; then see if there are actually 200 results; or any duplicates etc. Also try clearing your cache

Comment: @Ross few records are duplicated upto 15 times. espacially the first record. the php admin says there are 174 as show in the image

Comment: @Ross Strangely when i use $this->User->recursive = -1; i get 174 records. when i want to pull all the related models i am getting 200. any idea why it could be doing that ?

Comment: NEVER use recursive.  Set it to -1 in the AppModel and don't look back.  I believe they're even removing it alltogether in CakePHP 3.

Comment: @Dave how to set Recursive to -1 for all models ?

Comment: @Harsha M V - in your AppModel, do this:  `public $recursive = -1;`

Comment: Thank you @Dave so next time i want any joins i gotta use contain and pull it right ?

Comment: @Harsha - no, if you want joins, use "joins".  If you want extra related data where joins aren't necessary, use Containable.

Comment: okay now am a bit confused. I thought Joins were Containable. can you please point me out what the differences are ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you are running does not nearly match the queries that CakePHP will actually execute. CakePHP will also perform all the required joins to get related data. So, this is not really a proper comparison that you are doing.

Some of your relations might return double results, like `User -> CompanyA`, but there could also be a `User -> CompanyB` relation, which would trigger 2 result rows for 1 single user.

To see the queries that Cake actually executes, use the getLog method on your datasource, like:

```
$ds = $this->User->getDataSource();
$log = $ds->getLog();
debug($log);
```

Or use something like [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) to get a panel with all the queries by default (when in debug mode).

Comment: or should i use contain to make sure i get only what i want ?

Comment: @HarshaMV For performance, containable is always better then fetching everything, so that's always an option if you don't actually need all the data.